# Вопрос по WordPress генерация ссылок в редакторе tinymce

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

В редакторе через код при вставке ссылки, например `<a href="{site_url}/account/">...</a>`, далее переключаюсь на визуальный редактор и tinymce мне добавляет в ссылку `<a href="/wp-admin/{site_url}/account/">...</a>`.
Стоит дополнительный плагин TinyMCE Config с настройками convert_urls true, remove_script_host true, relative_urls false.

Эти настройки, если менять, то ссылки получаются не всегда корректные. То путь абсолютный, то добавляется ../ после ошибки в путях получаются.

В общем, вопрос в том, чтобы не меняя эти параметры, можно ли как-то избавиться от того, чтобы в ссылку автоматом не подставлялось /wp-admin/. Решение нужно универсальное, потому что вставить урл и не переключаться на визуальный редактор - не вариант. Писать абсолютный путь тоже не вариант.

Comment: А чем абсолютный путь не вариант? SEO-шаманство? Так всё равно WP хранит все внутренние ссылки в базе (на страницы, категории, и т.д.) как абсолютные.

Comment: При переносе или установке ssl сертификата все ссылки остаются прежние. Менять через бд вариант - но не вариант. нужно средство для тех кто не умет это делать.

Comment: При переносе - ладно - там все равно менять в любом случае.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561

Comment: Вопрос заключается БЕЗ использования абсолютных путей.

Comment: Я вам поясняю - вопрос поставлен неправильно. От использования абсолютных путей в WP не уйти, никак. И при установке сертификата надо менять http:// на https:// в базе, что описано в моем посте по ссылке выше.

Comment: В бд пускай как угодно будет, в редакторе нужно что бы было относительно без подстановки  /wp-admin/, и здесь даже вопрос даже не к ссылках а на кой черт редактор вот это вставляет -  /wp-admin/

Comment: Смотри сюда https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710  и послушай **KAGGDesign**-а